# Vectorize code with sum operation in octave or matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

How to vectorize the following code? 
Edit: theta, y are column vectors; X is matrix; alpha, m are scalars.

```
   temp1 = theta(1) - alpha/m * sum((X*theta-y).*X(:,1));
   temp2 = theta(2) - alpha/m * sum((X*theta-y).*X(:,2));
   theta(1) = temp1;
   theta(2) = temp2;
```

I tried the following, but the sum operation does not do what I want...

```
   temp = alpha/m*sum(bsxfun(@times, (X*theta-y), X))
   theta = bsxfun(@minus, theta, temp)
```

Comment: is `theta` a row vector or a column vector?

Comment: What does the `sum` operator do, and what do you want it to do that it is not doing?

Comment: the two versions are doing different things...The correct answer is below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a matrix multiplication to vectorize that.

Probably:

```
theta = theta - alpha/m*(X'*((X*theta)-y))
```